# I filed 83(b) election via certified mail but forgot to request a return receipt, should I file again?

Tags: united-states, taxes, 83b-election

I filed 83(b) election via certified mail but forgot to request a return receipt, I assumed that I will get a return receipt by default which I was wrong about.
The certified mail shows that it has been delivered. Should I send another copy again?